# Scalar equivalent of Avx.Reciprocal() in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, intrinsics

Using hardware intrinsics in .NET 3, I realize that:

```
float a = ..;
float b = 1f / a;
```

does not strictly yield the same numerical results than

```
Vector256<float> a = ..;
Vector256<float> b = Avx.Reciprocal(a);
```

Results are numerically close but not identical. Instead, in order to maintain the equivalence between the `float` and the `Vector256<float>` variants of the code, the following needs to be written:

```
Vector256<float> a = ..;
Vector256<float> b = Avx.Divide(Vector256.Create(1f), a);
```

How can I reproduce the strict *scalar* equivalent of [Avx.Reciprocal()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.x86.avx.reciprocal?view=netcore-3.0)?

Comment: I don’t think the specific binary result is documented even at the architecture level. Only the error. What are you trying to solve?

Comment: [`rcpps`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rcpps) (approximate reciprocal of packed single) is less accurate than `1.0 / a`.  But yes in theory it's possible if C# exposes [`rcpss` (scalar single)](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rcpss) which does exist in SSE/AVX.  Note that normally you'd do a Newton-Raphson iteration to improve the accuracy of a reciprocal from ~12-bit to closer to 23-bit, unless that low accuracy is enough.  In C/C++ intrinsics, `_mm_rcp_ss` exists for `__m128` vectors (affecting only the low element), so maybe search for that in the C# docs that mention `_mm_rcp_ps`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET 6 you can use MathF.ReciprocalEstimate
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.mathf.reciprocalestimate?view=net-6.0